# How to add values to self.to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

Right now, if I have a user object like @user.

I can do @user.to_json

What I want to do is add values to the json object rails creates. I've tried this:

```
@user.attributes.merge{ :catalyst_show => true }
```

But that errors with syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'

Any ideas on how you can add attributes to the json object?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879589 to start.

Comment: Ruby thinks you're passing a block to `merge`, instead of the `Hash` you intended. So to make it clear to Ruby, you need to disambiguate - see Sameer's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add parenthesis.  @user.attributes.merge({ :catalyst_show => true }) or @user.attributes.merge( :catalyst_show => true )

Comment: Omitting both, the `()` and the `{}` should also work in that case?