# to_json/as_json overriding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am overriding to_json in my ActiveRecord class:

```
def to_json(options={})
    puts options
    options.merge :methods => [:shortened_id, :quote]
    puts options
    super(options)
end
```

It's not doing anything to the options hash, i.e. it's not changing it.

I am calling it via

```
obj.to_json
```

I call puts to see if it's modifying options hash and it prints

```
{}
{}
```

Also, i tried this with as_json, no luck. What's the difference between to_json and as_json and why isn't this working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) returns the merged Hash:

> **merge(other_hash) → new_hash**
>   **merge(other_hash){|key, oldval, newval| block} → new_hash**
>
> Returns a new hash containing the contents of *other_hash* and the contents of *hsh*.

So you want:

```
options = options.merge :methods => [:shortened_id, :quote]
```

or use [`merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) which modifies the Hash in-place:

```
options.merge! :methods => [:shortened_id, :quote]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer if you can answer my last question 'What's the difference between to_json and as_json'

Comment: @0xSina: `as_json` is a pre-JSON serializer that produces a simple nested Array/Hash/... structure, `to_json` produces actual JSON strings, I covered some of this awhile ago over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6880638/479863